# How come does the c program print the number "2" please help explained?

Tags: c, initialization, printf, declaration, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun1(int a, int  b) {
    a = a - 3;
    b = a / 2;
    return b;
}

int main() {
   int a = 10;
   int b = 17;
   int c = fun1(b, a);
   int d = fun1(c, b);
   printf("%d", d);
}
```

the code runs I am just trying to figure out what it prints out and why.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What do you think the result should be and why? What do you get when you step thru that code on a piece of paper or in a debugger? Just trying to understand what specifically causes you confusion so that it can be addressed.

Comment: Do not be confused by the fact that `main()` and `fun1()` both use `a` and `b` as the names of local variables.  That name correspondence has no significance.

Answer (score 1):

In this function

```
int fun1(int a, int  b){
a= a-3;
b=a/2;
return b;
    }
```

the value of the parameter `b` is not used. So in fact the function may be rewritten like

```
int fun1(int a, int  b){
    a = a-3;
    return a / 2;
}
```

or

```
int fun1(int a, int  b){
    return ( a - 3 ) / 2;
}
```

(though the compiler can issue a message that the parameter `b` is not used,)

In the first call

```
int c=fun1(b,a);
```

the parameter `a` of the function is initialized by the argument `b` that has the value `17`

int b = 17;

So the return value of the function is calculated like `( 17 - 3 ) / 2` and is equal to `7`.

In the second call of the function

```
int d=fun1(c,b);
```

the function parameter `a` is initialized by the argument `c` that has the value `7` due to the previous call of the function.

So the returned value of the function is calculated like `( 7 - 3 ) / 2` and is equal to `2`. This value is assigned to the variable `d` that is outputted.

Comment: thank you so much